# Set kwargs in test of serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I wrote a serializer in which I used the kwargs in its validate() .
here is it:

```
  def validate(self, value):
    course_id = self.context.get("view").kwargs.get("course_id ")
    ....
```

now I want to write a test but I don't know how to pass the kwargs to it.

here is the test I am trying to write:

```
def test_valid_data(self):
    serializer = CourseSerializer(
        data=self.course,
             )
    self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
```

I test this but it didn't work:

```
def test_valid_data(self):
    serializer = CourseSerializer(
        data=self.course,
         kwargs={
            "course_id": test_course_id
        },

    )
    self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send context in your serializer with additional fields.

```
CategorySerializer(data=self.category,context={'request': request,'course_id': test_course_id})
```

and get using context inside your serializer.

```
course_id = self.context.get('course_id')
```

Comment: thanks for yor answer. this course_id = self.context.get('course_id') will not give me the kwargs...(i need the kwargs . for using context I should have rewritten the auto-generated methods in view.)